# Difference between doing and getting things done by someone else

Tags: meaning, sentence, sentence-meaning

A traveler stops by an inn and the owner of the inn says something in two ways below.

Sentence 1 - I will tie your horse.

Sentence 2 - I will have your horse tied.

In sentence 1, speaker will tie the horse himself.

in sentence 2, speaker will ask someone to tie the horse for the owner.

Is this explanation correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment [John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/15299/john-lawler) wrote:

> Instead of tying the horse, let's use "take care of" because that's what people would say. *I will take care of your horse* means what they will do it; and *I will have your horse taken care of* means that they will make (not "ask") someone else take care of the horse. Though in fact, at an inn, the innkeeper would have a stablehand to do it, so the "I" just means they assume responsibility for the horse's care.